# How to speedup a post http request in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, http, post

i want to optimize a post http request. My system is composed by a server and a client.
The client send an image and the server save it in the database.

this is the request:

`res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, :mac => 'String', :value => 'ImageData(stringa di 22k circa)')`

The server make this operation with the database:

```
    Started POST "/events/save_photo" for 192.168.0.113 at 2012-03-30 09:27:27 +0200
      Processing by EventsController#save_photo as */*
      Parameters: {"data_type"=>"image", "value"=>"!binary |\n         /9j/2wCEAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhE...(very long parameter", "created_at"=>"2012-03-                 30 09:26:29 +02:00", "mac"=>"00606E91E5D2"}
    WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
      `[[ (0.3ms)]  [1mSET PROFILING=1]
      [[Device Load (1.2ms)]  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE `devices`.`mac` = '00606E91E5D2' LIMIT 1
      [[CACHE (0.0ms)]  [1mSELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` WHERE `devices`.`mac` = '00606E91E5D2' LIMIT 1]
      [[(0.4ms)]  BEGIN
      [[SQL (2.3ms)]  [INSERT INTO `multimedia` (`created_at`, `data`) VALUES ('2012-03-30 07:26:29', x'f22b19237b63f1c8c40da49ae5eb68969dd3cf28193ba...',)]
      [[ (61.9ms)]  COMMIT
      [[ (0.2ms)] [BEGIN]
      [[SQL (0.6ms)]  INSERT INTO `events` (`created_at`, `data_type`, `device_id`, `element_id`, `multimedia_id`, `name`, `status`, `updated_at`, `value`) VALUES ('2012-03-30 07:26:29', 'image', 23, 163785, 1065577, 'photo', NULL, '2012-03-30 07:27:28', '--- 0\n...')
      [[ (36.6ms)]  [COMMIT]
      [[35m (0.3ms)] BEGIN
      [[ (0.4ms)]  [SET PROFILING=1]
      [[ (1.1ms)]  SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 1 FROM `devices` WHERE (`devices`.`mac` = BINARY '00606E91E5D2' AND `devices`.`id` != 23) LIMIT 1
      [[ (0.8ms)]  [UPDATE `devices` SET `elem_photo_id` = 163804, `updated_at` = '2012-03-30 07:27:30' WHERE `devices`.`id` = 23]
      [[ (78.9ms)]  COMMIT
    Rendered events/save_photo.html.erb (0.2ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 358.4ms (Views: 11.6ms | ActiveRecord: 246.2ms)`
```

In my opinion this time is not acceptable. i would that this operation become more fast!! is it possible?

make attention that i don't use Base64, this method make the image string longer, and i must save memory

Comment: and why total time is 358ms when View time + ActiveRecord time is 257ms?

Comment: save image in the filesystem, that'll give you some perfomance boost

Answer (score 0):

As you can see most of the time is spent writing to the Database (246.2ms) - which database are you using?

If you need a fast database you could use a non-relational database like [redis](http://redis.io/) or [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). When you say you must save 'memory' do mean disk space or RAM? Because such non-relational databases store the data in the RAM (don't worry there are persistant possibilities ).

Comment: Disk space.... the server machine don't have too much space in hard drive and the system must save many image

Comment: however i use MySql.... now i modify the code, the client send 10 photo in a single request. the server spent 1,9 secs to save that...but total time for the request ale 3,8 secs!! :-S 
What can i do?

Comment: why are you even storing the image data into the database? writing the image data into an image file would be way faster I guess. writing to the database simply **takes time**. This is no http/rails question in my eyes but a MySQL performance question. If you really have to store the image data string in the database check out [MySQL performance tips](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips).

Comment: mmm...because in this way there's more security.... if someone want to take that image he must hack the server and even the db.... in addiction the image are crypted too..... for me the security is very very important!!!